# Navigation to Different view results in SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective C, and cannot figure out the error I am facing right now. The app was developed by some other developer few years back, and I just have to change some images and upload back as new version (and underline API/webservice got updated). Everything was done fine, but one button in app is causing a crash.

We have two button in our main interface, one shows the listing near by user location, which works, and we have another to show all listing. The calling method for them is same, but when we use Show all listing interface in code it crash application with no error. in Debugger it shows `(lldb)` and generate `SIGABRT` in main `appdelegate` call.

Here is the button code

```
-(IBAction)btnAllResturantAction:(id)sender
{
[btnAllRestaruant setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"all_restaurants_tapped.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSLog(@"SearchView : Button CLick for All Resturant");

@try {
    HomeViewController *homeView1=[[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeView1 animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"SearchView: Button CLick complete");
} @catch (NSException *exception){
    NSLog(@"Search View: Exception in All Resturant %@", exception.reason);
}
}
```

When in line by line debug, I can see Log message of "Button Click complete" visible in debugger window, but just after that it fail and crash application, I didn't see any other error message even after I try `bt` in Debugger window, it shows all framework code. Here is `bt` result anyways

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x129d3, 0x0464e62a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
frame #0: 0x0464e62a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
frame #1: 0x04617664 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 101
frame #2: 0x043c539d libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 156
frame #3: 0x002ff065 project6`uncaught_exception_handler + 38
frame #4: 0x03eabebe CoreFoundation`__handleUncaughtException + 830
frame #5: 0x0396d0ae libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 100
frame #6: 0x04687d0d libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 14
frame #7: 0x0468793e libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 103
frame #8: 0x0396cfad libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 47
frame #9: 0x03dba7d0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 672
frame #10: 0x03dba51b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #11: 0x056ef664 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
frame #12: 0x056ef4a1 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #13: 0x006941eb UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 160
frame #14: 0x000abf7a project6`main(argc=1, argv=0xbff5587c) + 138 at main.m:14
frame #15: 0x0431ea21 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Can you guide me where and how I look for error, with this information.

EDIT:

I add Exception Breakpoint which generate this `bt`

```
(lldb) bt
thread #1: tid = 0x1368d, 0x03996dd0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 3.1
frame #0: 0x03996dd0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x03ed59ad CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:] + 141
frame #2: 0x008873cb UIKit`-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 740
frame #3: 0x00887ccc UIKit`-[UIViewController loadView] + 189
frame #4: 0x008880d8 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 154
frame #5: 0x0088ebde UIKit`-[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 114
frame #6: 0x008b1d37 UIKit`-[UIViewController(UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods) beginAppearanceTransition:animated:] + 202
frame #7: 0x008c4009 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1389
frame #8: 0x008d5bf5 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 803
frame #9: 0x008d6e3b UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 68
frame #10: 0x00ab2193 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 252
frame #11: 0x00787eb7 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 813
frame #12: 0x039ab059 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
frame #13: 0x0586780a QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
frame #14: 0x0585b4ee QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 388
frame #15: 0x0585b352 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 26
frame #16: 0x0584de8b QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 317
frame #17: 0x05881e03 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 561
frame #18: 0x05883674 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::flush_transaction() + 50
frame #19: 0x006b7f0a UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 8398
frame #20: 0x03defd1f CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
frame #21: 0x03de59ab CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
frame #22: 0x03de4dc8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1032
frame #23: 0x03de4706 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
frame #24: 0x03de451b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #25: 0x05719664 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
frame #26: 0x057194a1 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #27: 0x006be1eb UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 160
frame #28: 0x000d5f7a project6`main(argc=1, argv=0xbff2b87c) + 138 at main.m:14
frame #29: 0x04348a21 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: add an Exception breakpoint, and code will stopped on the error line
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: @Igor follow your suggestion modify question

Comment: add breakpoint on the [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeView1 animated:YES]; line. And check that homeView1 is not nil. Looks like you break HomeViewController in storiboard

Comment: I already did that and homeView1 is seen as object of HomeViewController, not sure how further to check what you mean by nil.

Comment: ok, simply add the following code if (homeView1 != nill) {[self.navigationController pushViewController:homeView1 animated:YES];} else {NSLog(@"homeView1 is nill");}

Comment: @Igor I did your code, it still goes to navigationController. the problem is it straight aways goes for main.m as soon as it encounter error, in the "all exception" breakpoint is stopping on that line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95920/discussion-between-sumit-gupta-and-igor).

Comment: "> is it straight aways goes for main.m" 
No, you use somewhere the nil object to do something. To main.m you goes because of system exception.
Where your code stopped with active Exception breakpoint?

Comment: agree, but how to track which object is causing this and where in code. I am not sure if it is caller class or my HomeViewcontroller class that is causing issue.